# Rails 4 nested form, how to display image thumb on edit form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-forms

Am using rails 4 nested_form to create a form for my model. Model Album has many images. 
Part of the form for uploading images looks like:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
        <div>
          <%= image_form.file_field(:image_file) %>
          <%= image_form.link_to_remove "Remove this image" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

How can I display a thumb for each image on the edit form? currently only the browse button appears when editing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code to show the thumb images.(Using Carrierwave)

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_form| %>
    <div>
      <%= image_form.file_field(:image_file) %>
      <%= image_tag image_form.object.image_file_url(:thumb) if image_form.object.image_file?  %>
      <%= image_form.link_to_remove "Remove this image" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You also want to specify the thumb version in your uploader file if you are using the Carrierwave, like

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
end
```

If you are using Paperclip, then you have to specify it in models like

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image_file, :styles => { :thumb => "50x50>" }
end
```

& your view for paperclip will be having

```
<%= image_tag image_form.object.image_file.url(:thumb) if image_form.object.image_file? %>
```